# Record audio samples directly to music file on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, sampling

I'm making an android app, and I want to be able to record some audio that's played on an AudioTrack to a music file, It seems like a good idea to me to make an ArrayList of the samples that are played, adding each sample as it's played. I've made something I'd expect to work, but nothing shows up under "Music" app afterwards. Please take a look at my code and tell me if this is the right sort of thing to save to music, and what I need to do to make it work. Look especially at the startRecord() and stopRecording().

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Afspl extends Activity {

    public DrawView vi;
    private Point size;
    Display disp;
    public int wide, high, cx, cy;
    boolean doPlay = false;
    Thread soundPlayer;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        disp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        try{
            disp.getSize(size);
            wide = size.x;
            high = size.y;
        }catch(Exception e){
            wide = disp.getWidth();
            high = disp.getHeight();
        }

        cx = 0; //tracks mouse x
        cy = 0; //tracks mouse y
        vi = new DrawView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(vi);
        soundPlayer = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                int count = 0;
                while(true){
                    try{
                    Thread.sleep((long)(duration * 10));
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                    if(!doPlay){
                        if(count==1)track.stop();
                        continue;
                    }
                    int note = cy * 12 / high;
                    if(cx > wide/2)note+=12;
                    int freq = (int)(440 * Math.pow(1.059463, note));
                    System.out.println(note + ", " + freq);
                    genTone(freq);
                    if(count==0){
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            playSound();
                        }
                    });
                    count++;
                    }else{
                        handler.post(new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                track.release();
                                playSound();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        soundPlayer.start();
    }

    class DrawView extends View{
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public DrawView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c){
            int red = 256;
            int green = 0;
            int blue = 0;
            int curInc = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<24; i++){
                if(curInc==0){
                    green += 256/2;
                    if(green>=256){
                        curInc = 1;
                    }
                }
                else if(curInc == 1){
                    red -= 256/2;
                    if(red<=0){
                        curInc = 2;
                    }
                }
                else if(curInc == 2){
                    blue += 256/2;
                    if(blue >= 256){
                        curInc = 3;
                    }
                }
                else if(curInc == 3){
                    green -= 256/2;
                    if(green<=0){
                        curInc = 4;
                    }
                }
                else if(curInc == 4){
                    red += 256/2;
                    if(red>=256){
                        curInc = 5;
                    }
                }else if(curInc == 5){
                    blue -= 256/2;
                }
                int width = wide;
                int start = 0;
                if(i<12){
                    width/=2;
                }
                else{
                    start = width/2;
                    if(red==0){
                        red = 128;
                    }
                    if(green == 0){
                        green = 128;
                    }
                    if(blue == 0){
                        blue = 128;
                    }
                }

                paint.setColor(getColor(red, blue, green));
                int height = high / 12;
                int starty = i * height;
                int endy = (i+1) * height;
                if(i>=12){
                    starty = (i-12) * height;
                    endy = (i-11) * height;
                }
                c.drawRect(start, starty, width, endy, paint);
            }
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            c.drawRect(wide-100, high-100, wide, high, paint);
        }
        public int getColor(int r, int g, int b){
            System.out.println(r + "," + g + "," + b);
            int red = (r << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
            int green = (g << 8) & 0x0000ff00;
            int blue = b & 0x000000ff;
            return 0xff000000 | red | green | blue;
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        int type = me.getActionMasked();
        switch(type){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            cx = (int)me.getX();
            cy = (int)me.getY();
            doPlay = true;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            doPlay = false;
            if(cx > wide-50 && cy > high-50){
                if(!isRecording)startRecord();
                else stopRecording();
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            cx = (int)me.getX();
            cy = (int)me.getY();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(me);
        }
    }

    public double duration = 1;
    public int sampleRate = 8000;
    public int numSamples = (int)duration * sampleRate;
    public final double[] samples = new double[numSamples];
    public final byte[] generatedSnd = new byte[numSamples * 2];
    public Handler handler = new Handler();
    AudioTrack track;


    public void genTone(int freq){
        for(int i = 0; i<numSamples; i++){
            samples[i] = Math.pow(-1, (float)(i / (sampleRate/freq)));
        }
        int idx = 0;
        int volume = 32767 * cx/wide;
        for (final double dVal : samples) {
            final short val = (short) ((dVal+1) * volume);

            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
            if(isRecording){
                toRec.add((byte)(val & 0x00ff));
                toRec.add((byte)((val & 0xff00) >>> 8));
            }
        }
    }


    public void playSound(){
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, generatedSnd.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        track.write(generatedSnd, 0, generatedSnd.length);
        track.play();
    }

    public List<Byte> toRec = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    boolean isRecording = false;

    public void startRecord(){
        isRecording = true;
        toRec.clear();
    }

    String name;
    public void setName(String str){
        name=str;
    }

    public void stopRecording(){
        Byte[] samplesNew = toRec.toArray(new Byte[toRec.size()]);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Song Name");
        alert.setMessage("Enter Song Title");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        final String name = "";

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int inter){
                setName(input.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int inter){

            }
        });

        alert.show();

        setName(name + ".mp3");

        File writeTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "name");
        if(!writeTo.mkdirs()){
            System.out.println("Dir not created");
        }

        FileOutputStream stream = null;

        try {
            stream = new FileOutputStream(writeTo);
            for(Byte b : samplesNew){
                stream.write(b);
            }
            stream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

The dialog comes up to enter a name when I click the box twice, but nothing appears under "Music" afterwards.